# consultar todos los datos de 2 columnas

Tags: php

necesito hacer una consulta con php y mysql, la idea es consultar todos los datos de 2 columnas, en especial de la tabla, id_usuario y vigencia_documento.

Quiero comprobar todos los datos para ver si un documento esta vencido y si ses así enviar un mail alertando, agradezco si me pueden ayudar o sugeriri ideas apara la consulta.

```
mysql> SELECT id_usuario, vigencia_documento FROM usuario
```

---

```
-id_conductorPrimaria   int(11)         
-nombre_conductorÍndice char(30)    utf8_general_ci     
-cc_conductor   int(11)         
-licencia_conductor int(11)         
-vigencia_conductor date            
-telefono_conductor char(30)    utf8_general_ci     
-email_conductor    varchar(64) utf8_general_ci     
-direccion_conductor    varchar(255)    utf8_general_ci     
-foto_conductor varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       
-status_conductor   tinyint(4)          
-date_added datetime
```

El dato que necesito evaluar es: -vigencia_conductore identificar el conductor para enviar un mail

Comment: añade la estructura de las tabla involucrada

Comment: -id_conductorPrimaria int(11)   
-nombre_conductorÍndice char(30) utf8_general_ci  
-cc_conductor int(11)   
-licencia_conductor int(11)    -vigencia_conductor date   
-telefono_conductor char(30) utf8_general_ci   -email_conductor varchar(64) utf8_general_ci  
    -direccion_conductor varchar(255) utf8_general_ci  
 -foto_conductor varchar(255) latin1_swedish_ci  
 -status_conductor tinyint(4)   
 -date_added datetime

Comment: dale justo debajo de tu pregunta en el enlace que dice editar y pega dicho código @Juan Bautista

Comment: ¿Y qué es lo que determina que un documento está vencido?  ¿Qué código has intentando para resolver tu problema?

Answer (score 0):

debes iniciar un método de conexión de base de datos en este caso te pongo Mysql

```
$mysqli = mysqli_init();

$mysqli->real_connect("localhost", "root", "", "nombre_BD");

$sql = "SELECT id_usuario, vigencia_documento FROM usuario";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

while ($fila.length >= 0) {
    if ($fila['vigencia_documento'] == 'valor a comprar') {
        # enviar el correo...
    }
}
```

en el if debes comparar el dato de la vigencia, ya sea con una fecha o con un booleano...

espero te sirva y la marques como solucionada By JJ

Comment: a idea es que si alguno de los usuarios tienen el documento vencido, lo identifique con el id, para saber cual es y enviar la alerta.

Comment: No me funciono, quiero comparar el resultado con el mismo dato pero restando le 2 días, no me ha funcionado

Answer (score 0):

Para estos casos de fechas, te recomendaría mejor guardarlos como fecha Unix (en segundos, con dato tipo BIGINT), facilita mucho la comparación y operación sobre las fechas. En todo caso, te paso esto, tal vez te pueda servir:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'usuario', 'contraseña', 'nombre_base_datos');

$sql = "SELECT id_usuario, vigencia_conductor FROM usuario";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $fecha_vigencia = date_create($fila['vigencia_conductor']);

//En tu caso como esperas que se avise dos dias antes, se agregan dos dias
if ($fecha_vigencia < date_create("now +2 day")) {
    //se envia el correo al id $fila["id_usuario"]
  }
}
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: las fechas deben ser en formato DATE() para respetar su funcionalidad, si usas el tipo BIGINT no te va a permitir ingresar datos como 2018-02-12 pues no corresponde a un entero grande; entodo caso debe ser un TIMESTAMP